# How to take input from a URL in Python

Tags: python, automation

I have a link which contains mail id's and I want to count the mails with same domain's.
I have to take input from the URL.

```py
import requests

def finddomains(input_):
   
    
    domainFre = dict()
    ans = []
 
    
    for i in range(len(input_)):
        
        findindex = input_[i].index('@')
 
        
        if input_[i][findindex + 1::] in domainFre:
            domainFre[input_[i][findindex + 1::]] += 1
        else:
            domainFre[input_[i][findindex + 1::]] = 1
 
   
    for it in domainFre:
        ans.append([it, domainFre[it]])
 
   
    ans.sort()
    return ans
 
 
# Driver Code
link = "url"
input_ = requests.get(link)

ans = []
 

ans = finddomains(input_)
 

for i in range(len(ans)):
    print(ans[i][0], ans[i][1])
```

error message :
--> 10     for i in range(len(input_)):
11
12         findindex = input_[i].index('@')

TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: What is your question? What code did you try to write? What problems did you run into?

Comment: Use the `requests` module to get the contents of a URL.

Answer (score 0):

try

```py
ans = finddomains(input_.text)
```

or

```py
ans = finddomains(input_.json)
```

these will retrun a dict

you can loop throw them and find the data you needed